# Setting Preference over Constructor in Template Member Function in Template class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, constructor

I'm trying to create my own implementation of a doubly-linked list for learning purpose. I wanted to use a template class to do this. I have a few constructors that have the definition like this:

```
template <typename TYPE>
class DList {
public:
    DList(const size_t size, const TYPE& val = TYPE());

    template <typename ITER>
    DList(ITER&& begin, ITER&& end);
};
```

(I have more code that I have omitted).

The first constructor copies the value provided size times (so `DList<int>(5, 2)` would copy the number 2, 5 times)

The second constructor copies a range (between 2 Iterators) in to the list. (so `DList<int>(other.begin(), other.end())` would copy one data structure in to the `DList`)

The question is that how do I set the preference of the two constructors? For example if I'm instantizing my class with this line:

```
DList<int> listTest2(6, 2);
```

The compiler gets confused and chooses the iterator based constructor over the size constructor and throws errors. I want to keep the template iterator constructor because I have other classes like that one (that implements other data structures) and the iterators is a class inside the class. (so `DList` has a class inside it called iterator, see below for more info on what I mean).

Is there anyway to set a preference over which constructor gets called. I want it to work like how I can call `std::vector<int>(other.begin, other.end)` and `std::vector<int>(2, 3)` and both work.

I have attached the header file for my template class below:

```
template <typename TYPE>
class DList {
public:
    struct Node {
        Node* prev;
        TYPE data;
        Node* next;
    };

    class iterator {
    public:
        iterator();
        iterator(const Node* node);
        iterator(const iterator& it);

        iterator& operator++(); // preincrement
        iterator& operator--();

        iterator operator++(int); // postincrement
        iterator operator--(int);

        iterator& operator=(const iterator& it);

        iterator& operator-(int scale);
        iterator& operator+(int scale);

        bool operator==(const iterator& it);

        TYPE& operator*();
        TYPE& operator->();

        Node* getNode();

    private:
        Node* data;

    };

    DList();
    DList(const DList& other);

    DList(const size_t size, const TYPE& val = TYPE());

    template <typename ITER>
    DList(ITER&& begin, ITER&& end);

    iterator begin() const;
    iterator end() const;

    void clear();

    void push_back(const TYPE& val);
    void push_front(const TYPE& val);

    void pop_back();
    void pop_front();

    void insert(size_t idx, const TYPE& val);
    void insert(const DList<TYPE>::iterator it, const TYPE& val);
    void remove(const TYPE& val);

    size_t size() const;

    const TYPE& operator[](size_t idx) const;
    TYPE& operator[](size_t idx);

private:    
    Node* mHead; /// @todo convert to iterators?
    Node* mTail;
    size_t mSize;

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: observe that with

```
DList<int> listTest2(6, 2);
```

you call the wrong constructor because you pass the wrong first argument: the `size`/`val` contructor wait for a `std::size_t` for the first parameter, so an unsigned value. But you send `6`, that is a signed value.

The right way to call the `size`/`val` constructor is

```
DList<int> listTest2(6U, 2);
```

Second; you use `&&` (rvalue) references; so you can use C++11; so you can use `decltype`.

Not a great solution but if you really want that `DList<int> (6, 2)` call the `size`/`val` constructor, you can use SFINAE and enable the template constructor **only** when `ITER` typename support the unary `*` operation (access to pointed value, supported by iterators but not by simple integers), so

```
template <typename I, typename = decltype(*I{})>
DList (I && begin, I && end)
```

The following is a full working (minimal) example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct DList
 {
   DList (std::size_t const size, T const & val = T{})
    { std::cout << "constructor 1" << std::endl; }

   template <typename I, typename = decltype(*I{})>
   DList (I && begin, I && end)
    { std::cout << "constructor 2" << std::endl; }
 };

int main()
 {
   std::vector<int> vi { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13 };

   DList<int>(6, 2);                   // print constructor 1
   DList<int>(vi.cbegin(), vi.cend()); // print constructor 2
 }
```

Comment: That's very interesting. I didn't know you could do that decltype. Thank you